# ASP.NET memory problem when changing culture

Tags: asp.net, ajax, w3wp

I have a strange problem with ASP.NET. Several sites on my web server run the exact same application. The application has a page that contains a Tab Container from the Ajax Control Toolkit which in itself contains a Calendar control.

If I set my culture in the web.config to be:

```
<globalization culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />
```

Then everything works fine. However, by changing this to:

```
<globalization culture="en-US" uiCulture="en-US" />
```

When attempting to load the page I get an out of memory exception and w3wp.exe seems to use all available memory.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was nothing to do with ASP.NET, it was a bug in a custom control that caused an infinite loop.